# Dict inside dict to excel export

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I am trying save a dict file to excel(I've tried to use xlsxwriter). 
Example:

```
      {'Mod1': {'A': 0.029999999999999999, 
      'B': 0.050000000000000003, 'C': 
       0.14000000000000001}, 'Mod2':{'A2': ....}}
```

I am getting the Mod1 on first Column (in excel) then the 'A' but not the scores.
My code is as follow, I think I must add a for loop but I don't know how.

```
row = 0
col = 0
score = 0
for key in ranks.keys():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    for item in ranks[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        row += 1
```

Any ideas ? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the data structure of your desired excel file. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small working example based on a best guess at the output structure you are looking for. If it doesn't quite match it should be easy to change. This is more of a data structure issue than an XlsxWriter issue:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

ranks = {'Mod1': {'A': 0.029999999999999999,
                  'B': 0.050000000000000003,
                  'C': 0.14000000000000001},
         'Mod2': {'A': 1.029999999999999999,
                  'B': 1.050000000000000003,
                  'C': 1.14000000000000001}}

for model in ranks.keys():
    worksheet.write(row, col, model)
    row += 1

    for key, value in ranks[model].items():
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, key)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, value)
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

For sorted `A .. C` categories you could replace the inner loop with something like this:

```
    for category in sorted(ranks[model].keys()):
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, category)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, ranks[model][category])
        row += 1
```